# null pointer exception in getstrings method hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Getting Null pointer exception in Driver class conf.getstrings() method. This driver class is invoked from my custom website.

**Below are Driver class details**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                 HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException
{
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();       
       //conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310");
       //conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:54311");
       //conf.set("mapred.jar","/home/htcuser/Desktop/ResumeLatest.jar");
       Job job = new Job(conf, "ResumeSearchClass");        
       job.setJarByClass(HelloForm.class);      
       job.setJobName("ResumeParse");
       job.setInputFormatClass(FileInputFormat.class);
       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/ResumeDirectory"));
       job.setMapperClass(ResumeMapper.class);
       job.setReducerClass(ResumeReducer.class);
       job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
       job.setSortComparatorClass(ReverseComparator.class);       
       job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
       job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputFormatClass(FileOutPutFormat.class);
       FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/output" + System.currentTimeMillis()));
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       var = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Getting NULL pointer exception from following two line of code

```
String[] keytextarray=conf.getStrings("Keytext");   

for(int i=0;i<keytextarray.length;i++) //GETTING NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE IN keytextarray.length
    {
        //some code here
    }

       if(var==0)
       {        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
       long finish= System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println("Time Taken "+(finish-start));
       }
}
```

I have removed few unwanted codes from above Drives class method...

Below are **RecordWriter** class where I use conf.setstrings() in Write() method to set values

**Below are RecordWriter class details**

```
    public class RecordWrite extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter<IntWritable, Text> {

    TaskAttemptContext context1;
    Configuration conf;

    public RecordWrite(DataOutputStream output, TaskAttemptContext context)
    {
        out = output;        
        conf  = context.getConfiguration();
        HelloForm.context1=context;        
        try {
            out.writeBytes("result:\n");
            out.writeBytes("Name:\t\t\t\tExperience\t\t\t\t\tPriority\tPriorityCount\n");            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public RecordWrite() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void close(TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException
    {    
        out.close();
    }
    int z=0;
    @Override
    public void write(IntWritable value,Text key) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException
    {

        conf.setStrings("Keytext", key1string); //setting values here        
        conf.setStrings("valtext", valuestring);
        String[] keytext=key.toString().split(Pattern.quote("^"));
        //some code here

    }
}`
```

`I suspect this null pointer exception happens since i call conf.getstrings() method after job is completed (job.waitForCompletion(true)). Please help fix this issue.

If above code is not correct way of passing values from recordwriter() method to driverclass.. please let me know how to pass values from recordwriter() to driver class.

I have tried option of setting values in RecordWriter() to an custom static class and accessing that object from static class in Driverclass again returns Null exception if i am running code in cluster..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value of key1staring and valuestirng, in Job class, try setting them in job class itself, rather than RecordWriter.write() method.

Comment: I don't have the value of key1string and valuestring in job class(Driver class) values are from output of reducer class which I need to retrieve it in my driverclass

Comment: Try to add the String[] keytextarray=conf.getStrings("Keytext");  in resultwriter after you set the value and verify if it is set properly.

Comment: I could able to use getString as ser property in recordwriter and retrieve it successfully but not in driverclasss. Please let me know how to retrieve values from recordwriter to driverclass..

Comment: conf is linked with job, so I am assuming that after the reducer is done, you are getting the conf from the job itself. Moreover, I can see that your are setting custom values into conf, just to pass through. I am not sure if it is the correct way to pass the values through.

Comment: Thank you for help. I could able to retrieve RecordWrite contents in Driverclass by creating custom class with Getter and setter and setting TaskAttemptContext object to custom class in RecordWrite and getting TaskAttemptContext object from custom class in Driverclass successfully. But that code is not working in Cluster.
Below are details
**RecordWrite Class**
`public RecordWrite(DataOutputStream output, TaskAttemptContext context)
{
SaveObject.setObject(context);
}`
**Driver Class**
`TaskAttemptContext context1=(TaskAttemptContext) SaveObject.getObject();'

Comment: FYI.. Job is completing successfully.. but whatever information I set in `recordwrite()` in job I could not able to access it after `waitforcompletion()` method in driverclass

Comment: Once the job is complete, the record writer would emit the values to file system right. Why not get the values from filesystem, rather than using conf to transfer the values

Comment: Yes I could get values from filesystem, but each time new output directory is created right I am not sure how to retrieve values from filesystem.. Please provide some examples.. I have written output of `recordwrite()` to File an retrieved it successfully in Driverclass by reading from file.

Comment: You can try this                                                                                        **if (job.isSuccessful()) {
 FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(config);
 FSDataInputStream inputStream = fileSystem.open(new Path(outputPath));
 //Perform your operation here. Get the stream and access the file.
 fileSystem.close();
}**. Also you should not worry about output path being changed, as the folder is same as mentioned during your job execution, and the number of reducers decide number of output files